# Setting up an OpenWRT router to create an isolated, non-Internet connected network

Tags: networking, dhcp, wireless-networking, openwrt

I've got an OpenWRT mini-router (GL-AR300M) that I want to set up to create a very simple local network on my sailboat to share some network-connected devices to phones and tablets.

This network will never be connected to the Internet, so I don't want it to try to route packets to an Internet that it will never be able to reach. When I connect on my phone or LTE-connected tablet, the wireless connection takes precedence and I can no longer access the Internet via LTE.

I *do* want it to set up a wireless network I can connect to and a DHCP server to hand out IP addresses, etc, so I don't have to set up a bunch of static IP addresses.

What's the right way to do this? I've tried setting the DHCP "Router" configuration to 0.0.0.0 in Luci, and overriding the DNS servers to use Google's DNS, but I'm still unable to connect to the internet when I'm on my isolated WiFi network.

Comment: you say "This network will never be connected to the Internet" then you complain that " I'm still unable to connect to the internet when I'm on my isolated WiFi network" well if you re not connected to the internet, yount access the internet, and you will never reach any dns servers.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `dhcp-option` on my LAN interface to `3` instead of `3,0.0.0.0` seemed to do the trick. ‍♂️